# url with id of selected option

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

Good day!I've a question - I need my activityID when I choose the type of activity to be reflected in my URL? something like *localhost/codeigniter/index.php/edit/show_activity_id/8*
but now I gt only *localhost/codeigniter/index.php/edit/show_activity_id/*
how can I correct it?

```
public function get_activities()  {  
      //set selected activity id from POST  
      echo $projectID = $this->input->post('id',TRUE);  
      $activityData['activities']=$this->editmodel->get_activities($projectID);  
      $output = null;  
      foreach ($activityData['activities'] as $row){   
      $output .= "<option value='base_url().index.php/edit/show_activity_id/'".$row->activityID."'>".$row->activityName."</option>"; 

      }  
      echo $output;    
   }
```

Comment: So it is missing from the option value attributes you are writing here? Well then most likely your $row does not have a property named `activityID` ...

Comment: Check your get_activities method in the model and see what all it is returning, if ID is missing just add it there.

Answer (score 0):

there was a extra single quotes. please remove it

activity_id/'".$row- should be activity_id/".$row-

```
public function get_activities()  {  
      //set selected activity id from POST  
      echo $projectID = $this->input->post('id',TRUE);  
      $activityData['activities']=$this->editmodel->get_activities($projectID);  
      $output = null;  
      foreach ($activityData['activities'] as $row){   
      $output .= "<option value='".base_url().".index.php/edit/show_activity_id/".$row->activityID."'>".$row->activityName."</option>"; 

      }  
      echo $output;    
   }
```